# when run python code some kind of error occured

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf


imagePath = '/home/sk/test_set'


image_list = tf.gfile.ListDirectory(imagePath)
for i in image_list:
   image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(i, 'rb').read()
```

when excute this code error occured

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sk/tensorflow-classify/photos/as.py", line 18, in <module>
    image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(i, 'rb').read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 115, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 75, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: 11.jpg
```

i think tf.gfile.FastGFile(i, 'rb').read() this is not properly working.
it works when file name is 1.jpg, but changing file name following error occurs

how can i fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the path `imagePath = '/home/sk/test_set'` is not correct or the method accepts relatives routes.

Check the example [here](http://programtalk.com/vs2/python/11892/TensorflowProjects/Misc/YelpRestaurantClassification2.py/)
There are a FLAGS variable where defines all the routes, follow the leed based on your file structure, and where do you have the proyect

Comment: FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('image_path', "test_set", """ test_set""")     i tried it but same error occurs